# Should we still use abbreviations in short URL?

Tags: url-shorteners

I know we're normally using short links for following feature

- Short
- Analysis

But for the **short** point it makes me thinking about a question:

**Should we use abbreviations in a short link?**

For example I got a project call **Andrew's code lab** and got a abbreviation **ACL**, then when we're getting a short link should we get `short.link/acl` or `short.link/andrewscodelab`?

For the full term you'll get more info about the link while you might not understand what the abbreviation means, but for the long term doesn't it mean it loses the short feature cause it's still long?

Comment: I would only say in cases where the abbreviation is understood in an ontology (such as a dictionary). Otherwise the meaning would be lost and no semantic value can come of it. Cheers!!

Comment: Its going to depend on your specific situation and your preferences.   As you point out there is a usability benefit of having descriptive URLs.   However there is also a usability benefit of having URLs that are short enough to fit.   You need to strike the right balance.   In some cases you may need a really short URL.   Maybe shortening the URL at the expense of readability allows it to fit in a Tweet.   In other cases, you may be able to fit a slightly longer URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with closetnoc, if the abbreviation is well-known, it's alright.

But if not, it will be hard to rank well with the keywords you want it to get ranked under since it has no semantic value.